# Want to write a C++ wrapper for ublas' project function

Tags: c++, matrix, ublas

Minimal code example:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>

namespace bnu = boost::numeric::ublas;

template<class M, class IA>
bnu::matrix_indirect<M, IA> project (bnu::matrix_indirect<M, IA> &data,
    int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2) {
    return bnu::project(data,
        bnu::range(row1, row2), bnu::range(col1, col2));
}

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

int main()
{
    bnu::matrix<int> m(4,4);
    project(m,0,1,0,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ -Wall project.cpp -o project
```

It raises a compiler error:

```
> g++ -Wall project.cpp -o project
project.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
project.cpp:16:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘project(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<int>&, int, int, int, int)’
project.cpp:16:19: note: candidates are:
project.cpp:7:29: note: template<class M, class IA> boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_indirect<M, IA> project(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_indirect<M, IA>&, int, int, int, int)
project.cpp:7:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project.cpp:16:19: note:   ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<int>’ is not derived from ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_indirect<M, IA>’
(more candidates to come, but these are not important here)
```

I guess my header for my version of `project` was not fitting (I copied the best suitable from `/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp`). How to make it work?

Comment: What's the problem? Compile error? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: Indeed, it is a compiler error. Added it.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear error message to me: "boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<int>’ is not derived from ‘boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_indirect<M, IA>".

Comment: Agreed, but why does the same function header work in `/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp` then?